# Check for blank entry

Tags: python

I am trying to get an input from a user and if it is blank entry I should see message with("please enter numbers")

I have tried using if statement and setting it equal to `None`.

```
def get_player_numbers():
    number_csv = input("Enter your 6 numbers, separated by commas: ")
    if number_csv == None:
        print("Enter something")
        get_player_numbers()
    else:
        number_list = number_csv.split(",")
        integer_set = {int(number) for number in number_list}
        return integer_set
```

I should be able to see
("Please enter digits , input can't be blank")

Comment: `if not number_csv:`

Comment: You also don't return the result of the recursive call to `get_player_numbers()`

Comment: try `number_csv == ""` instead of `None`

Comment: Recursion won't do anything if you don't return with `return get_player_numbers()` in first if statement

Comment: There is no `"Please enter digits , input can't be blank"` in your code

Comment: @Ben `input` will never be `None`, it will only be an empty string.

Comment: @Ben, it shouldn't

Comment: @AlbertoPoljak so I just return get_player_numbers() method?after if number_csv == "":?

Comment: @DanielTkachenko many answers here are wrong just because of that. Yes you need to change the line after `print("Enter something")`

Answer (score 1):

`input()` always returns a string. Blank input return an empty string:

```
if number_csv == '':
        print("Please enter digits , input can't be blank")
```

Due to the implicit falsehood of empty strings, this can be simplified to:

```
if not number_csv:
        print("Please enter digits , input can't be blank")
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this would compile because you are going to get an End Of File error. You should use raw_input() instead of input(). The difference is input() returns an object of type python expression, while raw_input returns a string. You are going to want to compare strings in this case. Your new code would be...

```
def get_player_numbers():
    number_csv = raw_input("Enter your 6 numbers, separated by commas: ")
    if number_csv == "":
        print("Enter something")
        return get_player_numbers()
   else:
        number_list = number_csv.split(",")
        integer_set = {int(number) for number in number_list}
        return integer_set
```

Note: now your if statement compares the input value to "" instead of None.

Edit: Thanks for the comment! I fixed the recursive call by adding a return statement if the user enters a blank. This needs to happen or when the user finally enters something the output will be None.

Comment: Also, as noted in another answer, you could change your print statement to print("Please enter digits , input can't be blank"), but I assumed you were really asking why the program didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use regular expression ([test](https://regex101.com/r/fp72U4/1)) to test input:

```
import re


def get_player_numbers():
    integer_set = None
    while not integer_set:
        number_csv = input("Enter your 6 numbers, separated by commas: ")
        if not re.match("([0-9]+,){5}[0-9]+", number_csv):
            print("Invalid input.")
        else:
            number_list = number_csv.split(",")
            integer_set = {int(number) for number in number_list}
    return integer_set


res = get_player_numbers()

print(res)
```

Output:

```
Enter your 6 numbers, separated by commas: 
Invalid input.
Enter your 6 numbers, separated by commas: 1,2
Invalid input.
Enter your 6 numbers, separated by commas: some-word
Invalid input.
Enter your 6 numbers, separated by commas: 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: can you please why you used while not integer_set?

Comment: @DanielTkachenko, as you see I set value of `integer_set` to `None` before loop. Inside loop if input is valid I set value to generated set. Expression `while not integer_set` means "loop while `integer_set` is not assigned". It's equal to `while integer_set == None`

Comment: oh ok makes sense, I thought that if its while not integer set it means while its not equal to None

Comment: @DanielTkachenko, actually, it means. `while not integer_set` in this code is same with `while integer_set == None`.